# I want to change the opacity for the first banner,but this seems doesn‘t work

Tags: javascript

Part of my code:

```
 <div class="banner">
    <div class="banner-img">
        <img src="img/14.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

The script:

```
var banners=document.getElementsByClassName("banner");
banners[0].style.opacity="0.5";
```

The Chrome Developer Tools threw this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

Comment: Are you sure the DOM is loaded?

Comment: if you type "change opacity with js" on google you will find your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `onload` event occurs later, when all content (e.g. images) also has been loaded

if you insert this script inside `window.onload` trigger function you guarantee the DOM is loaded and you can change the opacity.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var banners = document.getElementsByClassName("banner");
    banners[0].style.opacity="0.5"
}
```

Comment: but the script works automatically while  page opens

Comment: @LANSENLEE it depends on how you have structured your file (I don't know if everything is in a unique file or spread to many) your script will load before your dom is ready.